# AngularJS ui-bootstrap open modal window without changing the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using the ui-bootstrap module in my AngularJS project. Before I open the modal the url looks like this : localhost:58890/#/Project/46. The code that opens it is here :

```
$modal.open(modalServices.newItemModal).result.then(function (name) {
                    var folder = new Item({
                        id: null,
                        projectId: ProjectService.project.ID,
                        name: name,
                        type: ItemType["Folder"],
                        contents : null
                    });
```

The modalServices.newItemModal settings are here :

```
var newItemModal = {
    templateUrl: '/template/modal/newItem',
    controller: 'NewItemController',
    backdrop: 'static',
    size : 'sm'
};
```

after the line of code $modal.open the url changes to : localhost:58890/
Is it possible to prevent this, and make the modal act like in the jQuery modal where it doesn't change the url ?

Comment: How are you triggering the modal open from the html? I have an application locally ( triggering it with a `button` ) and it does not change the location hash by default

Comment: Uh.... it's triggered by clicking on a contextMenu directive that i downloaded, and it is implemented with <a href="#"> etc etc</a> so ye .... I changed the directive and it worked, :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling your modal open function from a anchor tag , DONT!

define a buttton in your view and in on-click event , fire the open modal function like this :

```
    <button ng-click="openmodal()">OPEN MODAL</button>

    app.controller('YourCtrl',function($scope,$modal){

    $scope.openmodal=function(){
        $modal.open(modalServices.newItemModal).result.then(function (name) {
                var folder = new Item({
                    id: null,
                    projectId: ProjectService.project.ID,
                    name: name,
                    type: ItemType["Folder"],
                    contents : null
                });

        }
       });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.. It was working before, but now I upgraded to angularjs 1.3 and It's changing the url. I tried putting ng-click on a button and on a div tag.